# RegEx - Extracting similar groups

Tags: regex

I have to interpret a bunch of files, where each line stands for some maximum float value.

```
{...}
SomeMaximumVal: 630.0 (AB300: 420.0) (AB301: 220.0)
SomeOtherMaximumVal: 610.0 (AB300: 410.0) (AB301: 210.0)
{...}
```

A single line hereby can either contain **just a common value**, e.g.

```
SomeMaximumVal: 630.0
```

or a common value and **one application specific value**, e.g.

```
SomeMaximumVal: 630.0 (AB300: 420.0)
```

or a common value and **more than one application specific value**, e.g.

```
SomeMaximumVal: 630.0 (AB300: 420.0) (AB301: 220.0)
```

or no common value and **just one or more application specific value**, e.g.

```
SomeMaximumVal: (AB300: 420.0) (AB301: 220.0)
```

---

Now I'd like to extract those values via the regular expression

```
\s*(?:(\S*)\s*:\s*([0-9\.-]*)(?:\s*\(\s*(\S*)\s*:\s*([0-9\.-]+)\)))
```

but e.g. the results for the file

```
SomeMaximumVal: 630.0 (AB300: 420.0) (AB301: 220.0)
SomeOtherMaximumVal: 610.0 (AB300: 410.0) (AB301: 210.0)
```

are:

```
Match 1
  Full match    0-36    SomeMaximumVal: 630.0 (AB300: 420.0)
    Group 1.    0-14    SomeMaximumVal
    Group 2.    16-21   630.0
    Group 3.    23-28   AB300
    Group 4.    30-35   420.0

Match 2
  Full match    52-94   SomeOtherMaximumVal: 610.0 (AB300: 410.0)
    Group 1.    53-72   SomeOtherMaximumVal
    Group 2.    74-79   610.0
    Group 3.    81-86   AB300
    Group 4.    88-93   410.0
```

which include **only the first** of each application specific value.

The question is: How can I extend the RegEx to include the further values, too?

Comment: The number of groups you get in the result is determined by the number of capturing groups you define in the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(\w+)\s*:\s*(-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kseieS/2).

**Details**

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)` - Group 2:

  - `-?` - 1 or 0 hyphens
  - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
  - `(?:\.[0-9]+)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of:

    - `\.` - a dot
    - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits.